# How to efficiently run range based queries in Cassandra

Tags: query-performance, cassandra

I wanted to use Cassandra in a project, but it's important that I'm able to do a few ranged queries (for example, `12345 <= time < 67890` ).

Unfortunately, Cassandra's design seems to preclude these sort of queries, except in 2 cases (and then [only for number or dates fields](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/confluence/cql-operators/)): if the queried column has a secondary index or if it has a clustered key. (Am I right about this? I couldn't be sure from the documentation, it looks like secondary index would only allow using the `=` operator)

My main question is: is there a way to efficiently run queries `BETWEEN` two numbers? Maybe in clustered columns? And if yes, how many of these columns can run such queries (i.e., can I have 3 columns that would accept ranged queries without a major performance hit)?

Related:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11348158/cassandra-query-with-where-clause-containing-greather-or-lesser-than-and
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29692738/how-do-secondary-indexes-work-in-cassandra
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24949676/difference-between-partition-key-composite-key-and-clustering-key-in-cassandra/24953331#24953331

Comment: The short answer is: no. Choose a relational database where you can add indexes as fit for your queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My main question is: is there a way to efficiently run queries BETWEEN two numbers?

Yes, but it depends on how you build the PRIMARY KEY.  Let's say that I have a table of users, and I want to be able to query them by age and state of residence.  I could build the table with a PK like this:

```
PRIMARY KEY (state,age,user_id)
```

Then, a query like this works:

```
> SELECT * FROM users_by_state_and_age
  WHERE state='MN'
      AND age >= 40
      AND age < 50;

 state | age | user_id                              | name
-------+-----+--------------------------------------+---------
    MN |  44 | 2176e0b2-313e-472a-879b-7cd2c404846a |  Jessie
    MN |  46 | 9cd1fa2d-ea7e-417f-a3fc-bf96d77b1aba |   Aaron
    MN |  46 | e6d28709-6e8f-4455-b158-3cc5c8f58b5c | Coriene
```

The thing with Cassandra, is that it can support a query like this, as long as you design the table to support it.

*Note: In this use case, I'd probably want an additional partition key, as partitions by `state` would likely grow unbound and cause issues with size eventually.*

*Edit*

> If one uses instead `PRIMARY KEY ((state, age), user_id)` to solve the problem mentioned in your note, would one still be able to run range queries on the age column

No.  `age` in this case is part of the partition key.  Cassandra needs the complete partition key to compute a hash and determine where in the cluster (which node) the data is stored.  For a range query on even a partial partition key, Cassandra would have to compute hashes for all range values and would end up sending requests to multiple nodes (which you don't want).

> Could secondary indexes be used for range queries?

No, that doesn't work.

> And what are the costs of secondary indexes, is it just the space they take?

Secondary indexes are essentially lookup tables which tell Cassandra which node is responsible for the indexed data.  So instead of reading data for a table from one node, it's reading indexed data from a table on one node and likely being redirected to another for the index.  Essentially secondary index query time will at least be doubled.

You'll also take a hit at write-time, as the index is kept in-sync with the table.

Somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29692738/how-do-secondary-indexes-work-in-cassandra/

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Hope it's ok to ask some follow-ups. If one uses instead `PRIMARY KEY ((state, age), user_id)` to solve the problem mentioned in your note, would one still be able to run range queries on the `age` column (like the one you used as example)? Could secondary indexes be used for range queries? And what are the costs of secondary indexes, is it just the space they take?

Comment: @flen edit made.  But in the future, do try and ask only one question per question.